# 'wall' object is not callable

Tags: python, классы, list, pygame

Уже часа 3 сижу и не понимаю что делать с этой ошибкой.

Ошибка:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matvey\Desktop\TUTA\besiege_client.py", line 137, in <module>
    walls = create(1, wx*50, wy*50)
  File "C:\Users\Matvey\Desktop\TUTA\besiege_client.py", line 90, in create
    walls.append(wall((x, y)))
TypeError: 'wall' object is not callable
```

Вот сам код:

```js
import pygame
import socket
from threading import Thread

hst = input("IP БЫСТРА >:(")
HOST = hst
PORT = 1531
sock = socket.socket()
pygame.init()
class player():
    def __init__(self, pos, pl):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 50, 50)
        self.pl = pl
    def keys(self):
        if self.pl == 1:
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_a]:
                self.move(-speed, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_d]:
                self.move(speed, 0)
            if key[pygame.K_w]:
                self.move(0, -speed)
            if key[pygame.K_s]:
                self.move(0, speed)
        if self.pl == 2:
            self.rect.x = player2_x
            self.rect.y = player2_y
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)
    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0:
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0:
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0:
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
    def draw(self, win):
        #win.blit(wall_texture, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), self.rect)
class wall(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 50, 50)
    def draw(self, win):
        #win.blit(wall_texture, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (159,159,159), self.rect)

#wall_texture = pygame.image.load('Wall.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
speed = 3
#pygame.mixer.music.load('kus.mp3')
oo = pygame.image.load("oo.png")
level = [
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O         OO       O                  O",
"O                                     O",
"O         O                           O",
"O               O 2    1              O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                                     O",
"O                  OO   OOO           O",
"O                  OO      O          O",
"O                        OO           O",
"O                  OO      O          O",
"O                  OO   OOO           O",
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"]
def create(what, x, y):
    walls = []
    players = []
    if what == 1:
        walls.append(wall((x, y)))
        return walls
    if what == 0:
        xw = 0
        yw = 0
        for line in level:
            for col in line:
                if col == "1":
                    players.append(player((xw, yw), 1))
                elif col == "2":
                    players.append(player((xw, yw), 2))
                xw += 50
            yw += 50
            xw = 0
        return players
walls = create(1, 0, 0)
players = create(0, 0, 0)
speed = 3
delay_kus = 0
x_kus = 1770
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
pygame.display.set_caption("SigSaw")
while run:
    delay_kus += 1
    if delay_kus >= 1000:
        win.blit(oo, (x_kus, 1080/2))
        if delay_kus > 1500 and delay_kus < 1900:
            x_kus -= 1
        if delay_kus > 2200:
            x_kus -= 1
    for player in players:
        if player.pl == 1:
            p2x = player.rect.x
            p2y = player.rect.y
    senda = "{}-{}".format(p2x, p2y).encode()
    sock.send(senda)
    pl2 = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    pl2 = pl2.split("-")
    player2_x = int(pl2[0])
    player2_y = int(pl2[1])
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mclk = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mclk[0]:
        wx, wy = mx//50, my//50
        walls = create(1, wx*50, wy*50)
    for player in players:
        player.keys()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
    for wall in walls:
        wall.draw(win)
    for player in players:
        player.draw(win)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
    win.fill((10, 150, 10))
```

Был бы очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь поможет.

Comment: У вас глобальном пространстве имен изменяется wall. Сначала это класс, потом внутри while вы присваиваете значения из walls. Переименуйте класс wall в Wall и исправьте на `walls.append(Wall((x, y)))`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Если бы не вы, то я бы никогда не догадался! Кто бы мог подумать, что проблема лежит в одной букве...